# Update 200k Records in SQL Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update 200k records with the following query in SQL:

```
UPDATE [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Contacts]
  SET Type_ID = 2
  WHERE [Company] = 0 AND (Type_ID != 2 OR Type_ID IS NULL);
```

I get the following message when the query completes in 25 seconds:

```
(195304 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

No records are updated after this. I then limit the query to update several or one record, for example like so:

```
UPDATE [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Contacts]
  SET Type_ID = 2
  WHERE Email_Address LIKE '%amazon.com%' 
  AND  [Company] = 0 AND (Type_ID != 2 OR Type_ID IS NULL);
```

When I run this, 60 records are updated correctly.

I am not sure how to begin troubleshooting this issue. Is SQL limited to less than x records on a simple `UPDATE`? How do I get around this issue? Should I write a loop to update 10% of records at a time or something along those lines?

Comment: Have you checked for triggers on that table? Those extra `(0 row(s) affected)` seem to indicate additional activity after your `update`. -- also, to clarify, sql server is not limited to a number of records for an `update`; that isn't the problem.

Comment: @SqlZim Thanks Zim, I will look into it. It seems strange to me that a small number of records get updated, shouldn't the trigger kick in then as well?

Comment: It should, but you never know what logic someone might have tucked into a trigger.

Comment: @SqlZim Suppressing the triggers on that table worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was, in fact, caused by a trigger. I [suppressed the trigger](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1591/disabling-a-trigger-for-a-specific-sql-statement-or-session/) and it worked (obviously you want to know why the trigger was put in place). The working code looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Contacts] DISABLE TRIGGER trigger_Name

  UPDATE [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Contacts]
    SET Type_ID = 2
    WHERE [Company] = 0 AND (Type_ID != 2 OR Type_ID IS NULL);

ALTER TABLE [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Contacts] ENABLE TRIGGER 
trigger_Name
```

---

Side note on something that does NOT work: I made attempts to wrap the code in `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` to commit the transaction before any triggers kicked off, like so:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  UPDATE [ExampleDb].[dbo].[Contacts]
    SET Type_ID = 2
    WHERE [Company] = 0 AND (Type_ID != 2 OR Type_ID IS NULL);
COMMIT;
```

This did NOT work.

Comment: What was in the trigger code that made it block the big update and not the little one?

Comment: It was triggered on updating a record with a specific id - some default user record. Apparently it blocks the whole update if the record with that id is included in the update statement (implicitly in this case)